# Force Empty Decimal Placeholders in Decimal SimpleType

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xsd, formatting

I have an XML that produces monetary amounts, which are often the result of currency conversions and therefore need to be shown with a good degree of accuracy (in this case, 4dp). I found out that while I can produce the XML with the numbers so listed, as soon as I enforce a schema on the XML, all the "unnecessary" 0 digits are removed. While I can understand this from a computer's point of view, we need to display to our clients exactly what our number accuracy is in all numbers, regardless of the value of each number. For their understanding, it is a lot clearer if we are consistent in that we always show exactly 4 decimal places on such numbers. Here is an example you can run to see what I mean (compare the Before and After results):

```
/*
This script will create a schema collection, use it and drop it, so there is minimal chance of mess left behind
*/
DECLARE @XSD XML

SET @XSD = CONVERT(XML,
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xs3p.xsl"?>
<xs:schema id="MyData"
  targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/MyData.xsd"
  elementFormDefault="qualified"
  xmlns="http://tempuri.org/MyData.xsd"
  xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/MyData.xsd"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:simpleType name="Money">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
      <xs:totalDigits value="14" />
      <xs:fractionDigits value="4" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Amount" type="Money" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>')

-- Clean if there is owt to clean
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.xml_schema_collections WHERE name = 'TestMoney')
    DROP XML SCHEMA COLLECTION TestMoney

-- use our xml bit above to make a new schema collection
CREATE XML SCHEMA COLLECTION TestMoney AS @XSD
GO

-- we'll create our xml untyped first, so we can check it before we change it
DECLARE @Untyped_XML XML
-- this is the real test, with the schema enforced
DECLARE @XML XML(TestMoney)

-- build some test data
SET @Untyped_XML =
'<?xml version ="1.0"?>
<Root xmlns ="http://tempuri.org/MyData.xsd">
  <Amount>1.0000</Amount>
  <Amount>0.1234</Amount>
</Root>'

-- try to apply the schema collection to our xml, and show something useful whatever happens.
BEGIN TRY
    SET @XML = @Untyped_XML
    SELECT @Untyped_XML AS Before, @XML AS [After]
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT
         ERROR_MESSAGE()    AS Problem
        ,@Untyped_XML       AS FailedXML
END CATCH
GO
-- We don't really want this schema; it was just a test
DROP XML SCHEMA COLLECTION TestMoney
```

Is there any way to force the numbers to be shown at full accuracy?

Comment: I thought I had it for a moment, using a pattern match to ensure that four decimal places were a requirement, in the hope that would force the result to be displayed in a way that matches the pattern. Alas, the canonical form of an integer has no decimal places and thus fails the pattern match even when entered with `.0000` after the unit value. Thus, adding `<xs:pattern value = "-?\d+(\.\d{4})"/>` to the simple type causes an error. See this [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510416.aspx). I do not want to have to convert all my integers to strings..!

Comment: I have started to think that maybe the way to solve this would be to apply a style sheet to the xml, making it look pretty (without actually changing the values). I think this, but I have minimal knowledge; it seems that coding should be used to apply an xslt transformation within SQL Server... which is way beyond my ken. I'm using an SSIS package to save the xml file, so maybe that would be the place to apply the transformation? Any pointers if this is the right approach to use would be very welcome! Using [this?](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_decimal-format.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it seems that there is no easy way to do this - my solution therefore is to sidestep the issue by *attempting only* to validate the xml. Then, if the validation did not give an error, I infer that the untyped_XML could successfully by typed and return it as correct. This has the downside that I will have to continue working with untyped xml, but it does mean that at least it looks perfect by the measure of the schema. To do this, I replaced the TRY/CATCH in the question with this:

```
-- try to apply the schema collection to our xml, and show something useful whatever happens.
BEGIN TRY
    SELECT @XML = @UNTYPED_XML
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT @SchemaError =  ERROR_MESSAGE()
END CATCH

-- If there was no error, then it is because the schema validated correctly, so show the original file.
IF @SchemaError IS NULL
    SELECT @Untyped_XML
-- If there was an error, then display it, with the bad xml
ELSE
    SELECT @SchemaError AS 'ErrorEncountered', @Untyped_XML AS FailedXML
GO
```

This is unsatisfactory, but it solves the problem I guess and seems like the best I'm going to get without applying stylesheets to the xml after it is produced (in SSIS, probably, using an XML task).